# IPython Autocomplete in PyCharm Run Window

Tags: pycharm, autocomplete, ipython

I am coding in PyCharm Community Edition and making use of the `IPython embed` function to debug my code.  When I run the code, the code stops on the line I have `embed` and the IPython interactive shell appears at the bottom of PyCharm in the "Run" window.  I can inspect my variables and run commands, but all the IPython autocomplete (i.e. tabs) and up and down keys (to retrieve previous commands) don't work anymore.  Does anyone know how to get this working from within PyCharm?

Comment: I don't know why the history search doesn't work (up and down arrows) but do note that default binding for autocompletion is ctrl+space instead of tab.